# SQL Server : select where with multiple values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure that can check for all records matching an indefinite number of values.

So for example take the following simple statement;

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE ID = @param1
```

However, `@param1` should be able to take a string of comma-delimited values and check against all of them eg:

```
@param1 = '1,2,45,16,476,324,'
```

I imagine this would need to take the values and then turn them into a temporary table, and then somehow create a sub query to check against all the values in the temporary table. However my T-SQL skills aren't quite up to tackling that on my own just yet.

How can I do this, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This blog post might be worth a read: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many split function version online, if you just google SQL Server Split function you will get 100s of results back.

A quick fix without a function would look something like......

```
DECLARE @param1 VARCHAR(100) = '1,2,45,16,476,324'       
DECLARE @param1XML xml;


SELECT @param1XML = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' 
                    + REPLACE(@param1, ',','</s> <s>') 
                    + '</s>   </root> ')

SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE ID IN (
             SELECT T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') AS Value
             FROM @param1XML.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
             )
```

### Procedure

A proc would look something like...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SomeProc 
  @param1 VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @param1XML xml; 

 SELECT @param1XML = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' 
                    + REPLACE(@param1, ',','</s> <s>') 
                    + '</s>   </root> ')

    SELECT * 
    FROM some_table 
    WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT  T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')  AS Value
    FROM @param1XML.nodes('/root/s') T(c))

END
```

Comment: This solution will work with int values. If that string will be an array of strings then it could contain some XML reserved chars (ex. &). At this point conversion from string/varchar to XML will fail (ex. `DECLARE @param1 VARCHAR(100) = '1,&2,45'`).

Comment: true, but I think OP has only mentioned int values separated by commas and, lets be honest, when did you last time saw a query where special characters separated by commas were being used :) very unlikely situation I guess.

Comment: It's true that OP's example uses only numbers but there is no mention regarding type of values. Also, somebody could try to use this method to send an array of `[N][VAR]CHAR` values.

Comment: @M.Ali I selected yours as the answer based on its simplicity compared to the other answers. You were correct in that I did only want to use numeric values in the input.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution - using XML query. 
Table variable in procedure is created for test only.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spTestDelimitedParam 
(
  @param1 as varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @xml as xml
  DECLARE @delimiter as char(1)
  DECLARE @test table (id int, description varchar(20))

  insert into @test 
  values (1, 'Row ID = 1'), (11, 'Row ID = 11'), (3, 'Row ID = 3')

  SET @delimiter =','
  SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@param1,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
  SELECT * 
  FROM @test 
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT N.value('.', 'int') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N))
END
```

How it works:

```
exec dbo.spTestDelimitedParam '1,23,4,11,24456'
```